# Low Level write Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, segmentation-fault

I have created a low level wrapper function for write in C:

```
void MyWrite(int fd, unsigned char *buffer, unsigned int length){
    len=write(fd, buffer, len);
    printf("Output Length = %u \n", len);
}
```

Now when I am sending the following:

```
MyWrite(fileDescriptor, 0, 1);
```

command causing Segmentation fault

## Edited:

I want to write ASCII value `0` not the ASCII character 48 i.e. `'0'`

Comment: you pass a null pointer, so why is the segmentation fault surprising?

Comment: So you're trying to read from address 0... what exactly where you hoping to achieve by that?

Comment: @barakmanos *from* address `0`, but still

Comment: @barakmanos no issues, was just confirming. :-)

Comment: If you want to write the ascii character "0", write that into a buffer and pass the address of the buffer - don't just pass the `0`. E.g. save a var as the result of `malloc(sizeof(char)*(buf_size))` and pass that

Comment: @ChrisSprague No need for a malloc for a single char.

Comment: @Eregrith right, but the function may be expanded to do more than single-character writes so it's worth considering writing the implementation to allow for different sizes of buffers.

Comment: @ChrisSprague But the function is OK as is. The only problem is when the OP passes NULL as `buffer` which he shouldn't do

Comment: Are you aware that you are not using the `length` argument? That suggests a bug in the definition of `MyWrite()`. Also you're assigning to `len` which is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's pretty evident. You *essentially* passing the `buffer` as NULL (`0`).

When `write()` will try to *read* the data from a NULL address, it's most obvious side-effect will be [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to pass a valid pointer from where data can be read properly. As you're writing a wrapper, I'll suggest , add a NULL check for the incoming pointer inside the wrapper.

---

EDIT:

If you want to write a numeric `0`, you need to pass a buffer containing that value. Some pseudo code:

```
unsigned char val = 0;
MyWrite(fileDescriptor, &val, 1);
```

Comment: I want to write ascii character 0 not the ascii character 48 i.e. 0

Comment: @NatashaDutta yes I think so, it's better with `unsigned` too indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the man page of `write` you will see the function ***expects*** buffer to be a correct pointer and therefore will not do any check before dereferencing it.

Hence:

```
MyWrite(fd, 0, 1);
```

will send a pointer to 0 to `write`, which causes it to segfault.

What you want to do is:

```
MyWrite(fd, "0", 1);
```

to send a string with the *character* `'0'`

Or `MyWrite(fd, "\0", 1);` to write a null character (I don't know why you'd want that though)

Nicer version:

```
char c = 0;
MyWrite(fd, &c, 1);
```

Comment: OP doesn't need to read the man page, it is obvious from the prototype of his own function.

Comment: Well, I meant OP doesn't need to read the man page in order to understand that he's passing `buffer` as `NULL`.

Comment: @ Eregrith what @barakmanos meant is like "OP doesn't ___even___ need to read...."

Comment: @Eregrith I want to write ascii character 0 not the ascii character 48 i.e. 0

Comment: @Vineet1982 Then replace by `"\0"`